# isolating part of a url with php

Tags: php

I would like to isolate a certain part of a URL if the structure remains the same:

ex. URL - http://www.URL.co.uk/87/318/carrot_cake/

it is the 318 part of the example above, however the number can range between 1 - 999999 - but will always remain between 2 x '/' and to the left of the title (carrot_cake in the example) this is where I strugling.

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.URL.co.uk/87/318/carrot%5Fcake/';
$id = explode('/', $url);
echo $id[5];
?>
```

**Update**: fixed code, and tested

Comment: @soulmerge ....... can u elaborate on that a bit more .. i think it should work just fine!

Answer (score 2):

If Moff's answer is what you need, use it as it is simpler. If it's not, does this get help?

```
<?php
  if (preg_match  ('/^//\d+//(\d+)//.*/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), $results)) {
    print_r($results);      
  }
?>
```

(My local PHP install is broken right now so I'm hoping that the syntax is correct.)